# Creating a table from a prior WITH clause in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH LAYER AS (
   SELECT 
      SPLIT(de_nest, '|')[OFFSET(1)] AS product,
      ....
      

   FROM `table`,
   UNNEST(SPLIT(LOWER(REPLACE(variable, '^', '-')), '-')) AS de_nest
) 
-- Filter out empty products
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `newtable` AS
SELECT * FROM LAYER WHERE product is NOT NULL
```

This leads me to the following error.

```
Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword CREATE at [25:1]
```

But I cannot seem to find a sensible way of resolving this. My first workload is doing the un-nesting of the first table and the second is doing some filtering on those columns generated from the un-nesting process.

Comment: Do you miss a join between `FROM` and `UNNEST`? Like `FROM table cross join
   UNNEST(` or the same with a comma: `FROM table, UNNEST(`

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann There is a comma after the from table. I edited the SQL as it would super large and didn't add much to understanding the problem.

Comment: @disruptive try create or replace as with... if it does not work please provide us a sample input so it will make easy to try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to put the CTE declaration after the `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `new_table` AS
WITH layer AS ...
```

EDIT: a complete example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `your_project.your_dataset.your_table` AS
WITH
  layer1 AS (
  SELECT
    'this is my CTE' AS txt),
  another_cte AS (
  SELECT
    txt,
    SPLIT(txt, ' ') AS my_array
  FROM
    layer1)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  another_cte
```

Creates the following table

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a full example please. I want to use the first layer and write to another after filtering.

Comment: @disruptive sure !